# Get single caret for QLineEdit and QTextEdit with focus events

Tags: events, python-3.x, focus, pyqt4

I have a panel with QLineEdit (for data A) and QTextEdit (for data B) on the same page. The problem is that the cursor is blinking in both fields and we can't see easily where is the focus. This problem with 2 cursors appears with the use of focus events (that I need).

I used focusInEvent and focusOutEvent on each field, like this :

```
self.textedit_desc.focusInEvent = self.Change_fi_desc
self.textedit_desc.focusOutEvent = self.Change_fo_desc
self.lineedit_ref.focusOutEvent = self.Change_fo_ref

def Change_fo_ref(self, ev):
    self.MyNeed()
    self.lineedit_ref.setCursorPosition(0) # left
    ev.accept()

def Change_fo_desc(self, ev):
    self.MyNeed()
    self.textedit_desc.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);")
    self.textedit_desc.setCursorWidth(0)
    ev.accept()

def Change_fi_desc(self, ev):
    self.lineedit_ref.setCursorPosition(0) # left
    self.textedit_desc.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 240);")
    self.textedit_desc.setCursorWidth(1)
    self.textedit_desc.moveCursor(13) # end of line
    ev.accept()
```

Because of the two cursors problem, i added a color change in the text edit field.
But I would like to have a single cursor even if I use focus events.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour: for me, only one widget can have the focus, so there is only ever one visible caret. Can you provide a simple, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem? Also, what platform are you on?

Comment: I prepared an example :
(http://imaginux.com/share/fichiers/download/cursor_bug_example1.tar.gz)

Just run main.py and look on the bottom right, you can use the Id product and Comment/description fields. Finally I realized the 2 cursors problem comes from the focus events, look at line 34 of main.py, but I need focus events for other features, so how to deal with ? I tried on Linux Mint 17 and Win 7 with the same behavior.

Comment: The problem seems entirely caused by those overridden focusIn/focusOut methods. Without that, the focus behaviour is normal for me (i.e. only one visible cursor). I have only tested on Linux though, so maybe there are platform-specific differences at play. Even so, it is still very unclear from your question what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated the post to clarify. The first time I was thinking of a normal behavior of cursors, but now my goal is clear : I want to use focusIn/focusOut methods and have a single caret. I use Linux too but I tried on Windows to check it wasn't platform-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with multiple cursors happens because you have completely overridden the default behaviour, rather than reimplementing it.

Since it looks like you only need to listen in on focus events, I think an event-filter would be more appropriate.

Here is how to use an event-filter, based on the example code:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.textedit_desc.installEventFilter(self)
        self.lineedit_ref.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
            if source is self.textedit_desc:
                self.lineedit_ref.setCursorPosition(0) # left
                self.textedit_desc.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 240);")
                self.textedit_desc.setCursorWidth(1)
                self.textedit_desc.moveCursor(13) # end of line
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            if source is self.textedit_desc:
                self.MyNeed()
                self.textedit_desc.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);")
                self.textedit_desc.setCursorWidth(0)
            elif source is self.lineedit_ref:
                self.MyNeed()
                self.lineedit_ref.setCursorPosition(0) # left
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! In the example you give, I did somes fixes to help further readers (waiting for peer review).

Also, could you explain the meaning of "overridden the default behaviour" please ? I am not sure to understand.

Comment: @renz0fr. Thanks - fixed all the copy-paste errors (I think). On your other questions: the `focusInEvent` and `focusOutEvent` provided by Qt aren't empty functions. They provide all the default behaviour for the widget when it receives or loses the focus (such as handling the cursor). If you override those functions, you either have to reimplement all that stuff yourself, or call the base-class functions so as to keep the default behaviour. Using an event-filter by-passes all that, and just watches the focus in/out events.

Comment: Ok thanks. And the event filter is called only for the widget where it's installed, so no risk for the rest of the app to be changed ?

About calling the base-class, I found something about that in C++, on a french website (easier for me), so I give the link there because it could help somehow : http://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/qt-curseur-qlineedit-80121

Comment: @renz0fr. Yes, the event-filter only receives events for the widgets where it's installed.